# Update table from another table SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ive hit a wall with what seems a simple procedure.

Update a table from another table, heres where i am:

```
DECLARE @oldcode  varchar(50)
DECLARE @newcode  varchar(50)


SET @oldcode = table1.OLDCODE
SET @newcode = table1.NEWCODE


UPDATE table2 SET [CODE] = @NEWCODE WHERE [CODE] = @OLDCODE
```

this results in:
The multi-part identifier "table1.OLDCODE" could not be bound.

cheers :-

the data:

Table1

```
record  OLDCODE NEWCODE
1   ZZZALF38    ALF38
2   ZZZALF38.1  ALF38.1
3   ZZZALF38.2  ALF38.2
```

table2

```
record  CODE    
1   ZZZALF38    
2   ZZZALF38.1  
3   ZZZALF38.2
```

wish  to change table 2 to:

```
record  CODE    
1   ALF38   
2   ALF38.1 
3   ALF38.2
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  You should also show sample data for `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: sorry.... a data example is:Table1  
record OLDCODE NEWCODE
1 ZZZALF38 ALF38
2 ZZZALF38.1 ALF38.1
3 ZZZALF38.2 ALF38.2
  
table2  
record CODE 
1 ZZZALF38 
2 ZZZALF38.1 
3 ZZZALF38.2 
  
wish  to change table 2 to:  
record CODE 
1 ALF38 
2 ALF38.1 
3 ALF38.2

Comment: @user3641134, sample data would be far better off as an edit to your original post - please click the word 'edit' under the question, and put the values there.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are using SQL Server and this is what you want:

```
update t2
    set code = t1.newcode
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t2.code = t1.oldcode;
```

Comment: will your query work in Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
update table2 set code=table1.newcode from table1  on table2.code=table1.code
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.